# One-Dimensional Rod Heat Transfer (probably really easy)

Tags: thermodynamics

I haven't had any physics beyond introductory college-level classes, so I only know enough to know that the following problem is most likely very simple for anyone that has an engineering background. That being said, here's the problem in a nutshell:

We have a 1/2" diameter stainless steel rod. 6" of the rod is in a 90° room, then it passes through an 8" thick hollow wall, then passes through 2" of foam insulation, a stucco wall, and finally there is 2" of exposed rod outside.

Is there a formula in which I could plug in an outside temperature to see what the temp of the rod is at any given point in the wall? We are somewhat concerned about the possibility of condensation build-up.

Comment: Can we assume that the rod doesn't exchange heat with the walls?

Answer (score 0):

The steady state for isolated (no heat exchange with the walls) 1-dimensional heat transfer is linear. So if you know the temperature of the rod immediately on both sides of the wall, you just linearly interpolate between them.
You may be able to assume that temperature of exposed pieces is uniform, in which case the temperature X inches from the inner side of the wall is $T_{int}+(T_{ext}-T_{int})*X/10$.
Again, this assumes both hollow wall, foam insulation, and stucco wall are absolutely isolating the rod - this is likely NOT the case.